# How to get clear the exception while sending mail from Java program?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse LUNA package. I need to send an email from my Java program. While running the program an Exception was thrown.

```
package a1;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class a4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try { 
            if (args.length >= 1) System.getProperties().put("mail.host", args[0]);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.print("From: ");
            String from = in.readLine();
            System.out.print("To: ");
            String to = in.readLine();
            System.out.print("Subject: ");
            String subject = in.readLine();
            URL u = new URL("mailto:" + to);       
            URLConnection c = u.openConnection();
            c.setDoInput(false);                   
            c.setDoOutput(true);                
            System.out.println("Connecting...");  
            System.out.flush();                
            c.connect();                          
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(c.getOutputStream()));
            out.println("From: \"" + from + "\" <" +
                     System.getProperty("user.name") + "@" + 
                     InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName() + ">");
            out.println("To: " + to);
            out.println("Subject: " + subject);
            out.println();       System.out.println("Enter the message. " + 
                     "End with a '.' on a line by itself.");
            String line;
            for(;;) {
                line = in.readLine();
                if ((line == null) || line.equals(".")) break;
                out.println(line);
            }
            out.close();
            System.out.println("Message sent.");
            System.out.flush();
        }
        catch (Exception e) { 
            System.err.println(e);
            System.err.println("Usage: java SendMail [<mailhost>]");
        }
    }
}
```

Exception thrown while running this program. My output screen as follows...

```
    From: skalyanasundaram1994@gmail.com
    To: bharani829@gmail.com
    Subject: hai
    Connecting...
    java.net.UnknownHostException: mailhost
    Usage: java SendMail [<mailhost>]
```

Comment: It sure looks like it's an UnknownHostException. What mailhost are you using?

Comment: @DanW `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()`

Comment: are you trying to send an email from you java application ?

Comment: yes I am trying to send mail from my Java app...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying "mailhost" on the command line which is not the valid DNS-name of a server.

You need to specify the name or IP-number of a mailserver willing to serve your application on port 25 instead.

Answer (score 0):

From your output, it looks like your `mail.host` is defaulting to `mailhost`, which doesn't resolve on your system.  At most companies, it's something like `smtp.example.com`, but check with your local e-mail administrators to see what is valid for your environment.